# Can I embed a browser or emulator view into vs code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, browser, android-emulator

I have recently discovered that Android Studio has a feature to display the emulator as a tab inside its own view which allows faster UI development.

You can click anywhere, browse files, etc. but the tab will always be there and you don't have to bring it to the front whenever you make a change and see how it looks.

Is there a way to do a similar thing with vs code on win10 with the android emulator for flutter or with chrome/edge for react?

Comment: Vscode is an electron app, so theoretically I think it is possible, but whether or not this capability is exposed out to the app UI I don't know. Have you browsed the extension marketplace? I just did a search and see a few candidates for hosting an internal webserver that seem like they could potentially work. [Preview on Web Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuichinukiyama.vscode-preview-server)

Comment: Yes there are some browser features that I've found like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuichinukiyama.vscode-preview-server But I'm more interested in the emulator

Comment: Ah, for actual device simulators then I think it is likely not possible since they are typically *not* web-based. I could be mistaken though, I don't know for sure but my intuition says it can't work. This isn't to say that somewhere out there someone hasn't developed a web-based simulator that accurately resembles the native OS, i.e. Expo has their snacks that run iOS/android in the browser, but this is React-Native, so they are just simulating the "native" side.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio code already has en embedded browser. You just need press Ctrl+Shift+P (i.e. Command Palette) and then type: Simple Browser.
As you type it, it will suggest automatically "Simple Browser: Show".
Select it by enter, and then type your desired URL and press enter to load it.
For an embedded emulator, you can find it on extensions tab. Press Ctrl+Shift+X and type "Android iOS Emulator". Then choose the first one and install it. That's all you need.